# Calculate decimal exponent without nth root or logarithms

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have programmed a BigDecimal class and am working on a Pow method. I am stuck on doing decimal exponents as it requires you to have a nth root method, which further requires you to have logarithms, which further requires you to have a Pow method, and it goes in a circle. What is a way to calculate a decimal exponent without going in this circle

Comment: You can precisely calculate logarithms (or nth roots directly) by Taylor series or different polynomial approximations, taking as many terms as needed.

Comment: See [this](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root) article on Rosetta code. Also, you can use the [shifting nth root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm)

Comment: Meta-cheating, there has to be a way out of the catch-22 cycle that you describe, otherwise no modern math oriented software could work.  So intuitively, it makes sense that the escape clause is to calculate logarithms or nth roots by other means.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Is there an article on either of those methods?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer, I am open to feedback on how to do this better.
I learned yesterday that fractions, decimals, and improper fractions work like regular multiplication and division with a twist. In the case of an exponent (2/3) we are cutting the base into three equal pieces that if multiplied together will equal the base. The second thing is that we multiply back in 2 pieces of the base. For example:

2^0.5 or 2^1/2 is one square-root
2^1.5 or 3/2 is square-rooted, and then it takes those square roots and multiplies them by themselves 3 times. This helps when doing awkward decimals.
2^0.37 would be cut into 100 equal multipliers, and then "adding" back in the 37 pieces that are there.
I don't think I have the correct notation, but I would use (37*the 100th root)*numeral, as the 100th root would act more like bx +c situation but with multiplication.
For something more complicated like 12^x = 24^y
(3*2^2)^x = (3*2^3)^y
I think we can drop the *3 momentarily to focus on the similar parts
(2^2)^x = (2^3)^y
When I made the equation 4 = (2^3)^y that y was = 2/3
and also inverse for x = 3/2, I was looking for a cleaner way to deal with these without using log until the last minute, if at all.

Let me know if you have questions about my explanation, I am not comfortable with English.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In computer programming, I would set a variable for the nth root, and make it a math variable like x, y, z or something so the program can compute the rest of the equation and leave the ugly roots for last.